# Trying to deploy my app, but can't see the frontend in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, web-applications

guys. I'm trying to deploy my app to Gh Pages, before that I tried to deploy it Heroku...nothing works. Please help. My code's here: https://github.com/ed1707/kuwerkoapp-new

On my GH page it says that my app is published:
[image: Your site is published]

But when I try to open it up in the brower, this is all I get:
[image: My homepage]

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing codes, which I should upload to Gh page as well?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku apps include a Procfile that specifies the commands that are executed by the app on startup. You can use a Procfile to declare a variety of process types, including:

- Your app’s web server
- Multiple types of worker processes
- A singleton process, such as a clock
- Tasks to run before a new release is deployed

Please review your installation configuration according to [this document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)